# Allure tries to run a report on a wrong port in intelij idea and npm

Tags: intellij-idea, npm, allure

I have allure setup in our work project. At work it runs fine and command "allure generate ./allure-results -c && allure open", generates a report and runs it autmaticaly in browser. But at home when i run this comand it opens a browser page with no internet. But if i manualy run index.html from allure folder with browser it works fine. The only difference is : utomaticaly it tries to run on http://172.200.101.123:65249 and from ide manualy it runs on http://localhost:63342/

Comment: How exactly do you run it from the IDE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as i understand, default allure's ip and port is blocked by windows and i don't know how to unblock them. so i found a workaround: tell allure to run a report on a localhost like this:

```
allure serve target/allure-results --host localhost --port 9999
```